# radeon failed vce resume after upgrade to newest Linux kernel

Tags: debian, xfce, x-server, amd-graphics, radeon

I have upgraded my Debian to latest version on the kernel version 3.16.0-4-amd64. Update went fine. After that I decided to upgrade linux kernel version to the latest one supported by Debian 10 - 4.19.0-5-amd64. After reboot my X-server didn't get up and in logs when system starting I see an error like that `radeon 0000:01:00.0 failed VCE resume (-110)`

Laptom model: `Samsung 300E5V/300E4EV/270E5EV/270E4EV/2470EV/2470EE`

After sysmtem start I get in command line interface. When try to execute `startx` I see then same error about radeon and message from x-server:

[image]

```
$lspci | grep VGA

radeon failed VCE resume (-110)
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller(rev 09)
```

Here is `ls -pci` [log](https://pastebin.com/3SUh0zXM) and [log](https://pastebin.com/jS66q0GC) from Xorg.0.log file.

Could you help me please fix an issue and get my desktop up again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that helped me:

1. Add non-AMD drivers into the blacklist in file `/etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf`:

```
blacklist radeon
```

2. Put into `/etc/modprobe.d/amdgpu.conf` the following statements:

```
options amdgpu si_support=1
options amdgpu cik_support=1
```

After that, the error message disappeared.